# How to remove leading/trailing white spaces from a line of integers?

Tags: java, formatting

I have to print out the table in a matrix like fashion, each number formatted to a width of 4 (The numbers are right-aligned and strip out leading/trailing spaces on each line). The first 3 line will look like:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=12;j++){
            System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

In the output the first integer gets shifted by 3 spaces.How to strip out the leading/trailing spaces on each line?

Comment: The code looks like Java, but please specify in you question which language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll want to get rid of all useless whitespaces in between, why not avoid them in the first place?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 3, columns = 12;

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
            // figure out the max # of digits needed
            int necessaryDigits;
            if (rows * j < 10) {
                necessaryDigits = 1;
            } else if (rows * j < 100) {
                necessaryDigits = 2;
            } else if (rows * j < 1000) {
                necessaryDigits = 3;
            } else {
                necessaryDigits = 4;
            }
            // print them accordingly with one extra space to distinguish
            // the numbers and avoid the leading one in 1st column
            System.out.format("%" + (necessaryDigits + (j == 1 ? 0 : 1))
                    + "d", i * j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
2 4 6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36
```

output or for 10 rows:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  20  22  24
 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27  30  33  36
 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36  40  44  48
 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45  50  55  60
 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54  60  66  72
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63  70  77  84
 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72  80  88  96
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81  90  99 108
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your idea and did it a little differently according to the question and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the first number same as i out of your second loop and start your second loop from second i.e. 2 like:

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    System.out.print(i);
    for(j=2;j<=12;j++){
         System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: but then the numbers wouldn't be right aligned anymore if the first loop would be limited by 10 instead of 3...

Comment: It would.. why not @xmoex?

Comment: Actually this question was given in a competetive programming site. I tried submit the same code as you but it passes paritially. This is such a simple question still driving me crazy.Any other suggestion is appreciated

Comment: 1st: there's still whitespaces between the numbers, what about them? 2nd: if the fist number is 10 or above, then it's not right-aligned with the numbers above it anymore, because it consumes two character spaces instead of just one

Answer (score 0):

if allowed to put the condition you have like this
int i, j;

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    System.out.format("%d", i * j);
                }
                else
                 {
                    System.out.format("%4d", i * j);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```